# SSL with Angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli

How does one trust the SSL certificates that are self generated by the NG serve command?

Steps to reproduce:

Enviroment (`ng --version`)

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.1
Node: 10.15.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.4
```

Create a new project with `ng new myApp`.

change the `package.json` to contain `"start": "ng serve --ssl"`

run `npm start`

navigate to https://localhost:4200

This will now throw a certifcate error for the cert that is generated.

I'm specifically looking for a way to trust the certifcates generically, as I know I can just install the gen'd cert, but that only works for a month.

I also am not particularly keen to self gen the certs, as I want it to "just"
 work across multiple projects.

Comment: If you don't want to generate a cert.. with all obvious caveats aside, have you tried using the `--ignore-certificate-errors` chrome flag?

Comment: I dont want to hand generate the cert, I want to trust the CA that webpack is using under the hood. ( eg not https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a )

Comment: It depends on the browser policy. Firefox and Chrome have different policies on how to install certificates and trust them. For instance Chrome attempts to use the root certificate store of the underlying operating system .  [chromium docs](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy) Firefox does not use the operating system's certificate store by default.   [Mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/AddRootToFirefox)

Answer (score 0):

I'll start from the end.

As far as making this "just" work goes - there are 2 ways you can go about it.

1) **Generate a self-signed wildcard certificate for your local domain.**  Yes, you will need to host all of your local websites as subdomains of one root domain, but it's a whole lot easier than the alternative, which is:

2) **Dynamically generated SSL certificates.**  Which, while not impossible, is not exactly child's play, and the fact you've asked this question in the first place leads me to think that you wouldn't quite be up to that task just yet.  You don't just have the dynamic generation of the certificates to take care of, you also need to get the web server in on the act.  There is a fork of Nginx which will let you do this (link below), but honestly, I'd advise you to save yourself the headache.

https://blog.dutchcoders.io/openresty-with-dynamic-generated-certificates/

With regard to creating a self-signed certificate to use with your Angular projects and adding it to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store, I believe this article describes everything you need:

https://medium.com/@richardr39/using-angular-cli-to-serve-over-https-locally-70dab07417c8